# Regex to match any number (Real, rational along with signs)

Tags: java, regex

I've written a regex to match any number:

- Positive and Negative
- Decimal
- Real Numbers

The following regex does well but there's one drawback

```
([\+\-]{1}){0,1}?[\d]*(\.{1})?[\\d]*
```

It is positive for inputs such as **+** or **-** as well. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The regex should work with the following inputs

5, +5, -5, 0.5, +0.5, -0.5, .5, +.5, -.5

and shouldn't match the following inputs

+

-

+.

-.

.

**Here is the answer by tchrist, works perfectly.**

```
(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[.]?[0-9])(?:[0-9]*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0-9]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0-9]+))|))
```

Comment: That won’t work, for a bunch of reasons. The actual pattern you meant to write once all your confusing syntax errors and careless embellishments are cleared up is the very simple `[-+]?\d*\.?\d*`, but that obviously doesn’t work because you have to deal with forcing there to be some digits. The easiest way is with an or-branch. See my answer.

Comment: @tchrist Your answer works, I've posted it on my question also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something that looks like a C float, here’s how to tickle Perl into coughing out a regex that does that, using the [Regexp::Common module from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aCommon):

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common -le 'print $RE{num}{real}'
(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[.]?[0123456789])(?:[0123456789]*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[0123456789]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[0123456789]+))|))
```

You can tune that a bit if you want, but that gives you the basic idea.

It’s really remarkably flexible.  For example, this spits out a pattern for base-2 real numbers taht allow commas every three places:

```
$ perl -MRegexp::Common -le 'print $RE{num}{real}{-base => 2}{-sep => ","}{-group => 3}'
(?:(?i)(?:[+-]?)(?:(?=[.]?[01])(?:[01]{1,3}(?:(?:[,])[01]{3})*)(?:(?:[.])(?:[01]{0,}))?)(?:(?:[E])(?:(?:[+-]?)(?:[01]+))|))
```

The [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anumber) shows that the full possible syntax for the numeric patterns it can spit out for you is:

```
$RE{num}{int}{-base}{-sep}{-group}{-places} 
$RE{num}{real}{-base}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group}{-expon} 
$RE{num}{dec}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group}{-expon} 
$RE{num}{oct}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group}{-expon} 
$RE{num}{bin}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group}{-expon} 
$RE{num}{hex}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group}{-expon} 
$RE{num}{decimal}{-base}{-radix}{-places}{-sep}{-group} 
$RE{num}{square} 
$RE{num}{roman}
```

Making it really to customize it for whatever you want.  And yes, of course you can use these patterns in Java.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you tchrist, will try and get back to you.

Comment: @RagunathJawahar Glad it helped. If you really want to learn regexes, might as well do quick test-work in Perl, where they’re built right into the language, and have debugging and tracing abilities. Most of the simpler stuff ports to Java without change, especially if you use Java 7.

Answer (score 4):

You need to require at least one digit, i.e. using `+` instead of `*` for the `\d`.

I think you can also drop the `{1}` in several places since this is implied by default

Similarly `{0,1}` can be dropped when followed by `?`

Giving us:

```
regex = "[+-]?(\\d+|\\d*\\.?\\d+)";
```

Comment: Please do, much appreciated. Also please check the question once again, I've made some edits.

Comment: thank you. Checked it out. Amazing! works well, and shorter than the answer I've accepted. Do you see any difference between the answer on the question and the one you've written? Your's handles pretty much all the cases I've tried. Will check if it misses anything.

Comment: I realized the `+` and `-` don't need escaping within `[]` so have simplified it further.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
[+-]?\d*(\.\d+)?
```

EDIT:

I've improved it so it will not match the dot on `-123.` but it will for `123.456`

EDIT2:

So it doesn't match only + or -, you can check that such a sign must precede either a dot or a number, the dot being optional.

```
[+-]?(?=[\.?\d])\d*(\.\d+)?
```

Comment: Matches '+', it should return false if only + or - is entered

Comment: @RagunathJawahar It’s shorter because it doesn’t handle exponentials. It’s also wrong. There’s a lookahead that matches a literal dot (needlessly escaped in a bracketed charclass) or a literal question mark or a digit. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

This simple expression worked for me using Python:

-?\d+(.\d+)?

You can test it using https://regex101.com/

[Example of some values tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL04d.png)