# Regex in java positive or negative double

Tags: java, regex, validation

I need a regex for validation positive or negative double. I tried the following regex:

```
^[-+]?\\d+(\\.{0,1}(\\d+?))?$
```

but it allows leading 0s (e.g. 01 and 00). How I modify my regex so that it doesn't allow leading 0s?

Comment: You can use: `^[-+]?[1-9]\d*(?:\.?\d+)?$`

Comment: Why don't you use Double.parseDouble(myString) in a try catch block ?

Comment: it's not thank you that you find. anubhava

Comment: @jeanr `try`/`catch` can actually be relatively expensive. Also, that wouldn't work for the OP's purposes because something like 0001 is a perfectly valid double but he wants to reject that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to match any number (Real, rational along with signs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341695/regex-to-match-any-number-real-rational-along-with-signs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example (.NET syntax, should be OK in Java too):

```
^[+-]?(([1-9]\d*)|0)(\.\d+)?
```

Basically, this has an optional + or - symbol followed by either 0 or a number from 1 - 9 followed by an arbitrary number of digits. Optionally, it can contain a decimal point followed by one or more numbers.

The important thing about this regex (and this is what addresses your problem) is that it has the added restriction that multi-digit numbers can't start with 0 - you can have something that equals *exactly* 0, but you can't have something like 000010.1 or 0000.0 or anything like that. Something like 0 or 0.0 or 100.1 would be OK.

Comment: In Java backslashes need to be escaped by a backslash, so `\d` and `\.` need to be changed to `\\d` and `\\.` (else Java thinks you are using the backslash as escape character and it will not get passed over to the regex engine). For the rest, yes it is Java compatible.

Comment: @psilos You may have to replace the \ with \\ (I was testing it in .NET rather than Java).

Comment: Thank the two of you. The correct is ** ^[+-]?(([1-9]\\d*)|0)(\\.\\d+)?** in Java.Sorry for the bed format of my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative, which handles exponents, if you want them:

```
^[+-]?([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]+)?((e|E)[+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

I just now realised, that it essentially is the same as @EJoshuaS' with the exponent addition.

Here is a link to verify it:

https://regex101.com/r/WEaNLR/4

Comment: I like the link to *regex101*. Note that it also explains the regex step by step there, nice tool for OP to know.

Comment: This doesn't match `1.2`